# Install IOS app from itunes by clicking an URL

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, itunes

I have a requirement where user will tap a link ( iTunes link of **free** App ) which he receives in an email on iPad.The App should get installed on iPad, provided that the user is logged in iTunes.

Please let me know, how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a link to a user and they select it on their iPad (for example, in the format of `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appname/id364304764?mt=8`), they will be forwarded on to the App Store app, with the Application information page presented to them. The user will have to explicitly press "Free" then "Install" to install the application. At this point, they will probably have to enter their iTunes password to continue.

There is no way to circumvent this, everyone has to go through the same procedure to install an application; through the App Store*.

*Unless it's an Enterprise application, but they shouldn't be distributed to clients, as that'll break the enterprise service agreement.